# Parallelizing feature tools dfs

Tags: featuretools

I tried a similar code to this snippet

```py
ft.dfs(entityset = es,
        target_entity = ..., 
        n_jobs=-1,) # or n_jobs=40
```

But it doesn't seem to work on a machine with 40 threads:

```
S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
S  0.0  0.7  0:00.00 python test.py
S  0.0  0.7  0:00.00 python test.py
S  0.0  0.7  0:00.00 python test.py
S  0.0  0.7  0:00.00 python test.py
S  0.0  0.7  0:00.00 python test.py
S  0.0  0.7  0:00.00 python test.py
S  0.0  0.7  0:00.00 python test.py
R 78.0  0.7 23:24.72 python test.py
```

As you can see, there's no 40 processes and a single one is running (varying from 78-100% on that thread). Does anyone know what is happening here? I left this running for 25 minutes before killing it and I didn't see any change in the usage.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that Featuretools has not reached the parallelized part of the `dfs` function.  Feature calculation is parallelized but currently the feature exploration step (DeepFeatureSynthesis) is not.  You could check if this is the issue by setting `features_only=True` in the `dfs` call and seeing how long that takes to run.  You could then use the `calculate_feature_matrix` method to compute the returned features.